# Compile java project without using gradle's java plugin?

Tags: java, gradle

So, my `build.gradle` looks something like this,

```
task compile(type: Compile){
    dependsOn 'clean', 'init'

    classpath = files('bin', 
                    'lib\\foo-agent-dist-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar',
                    'lib\\foo-common-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar',
                    'lib\\foo-communication-api-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar',
                    'lib\\spring-beans-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar',
                    'lib\\spring-context-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar',
                    'lib\\spring-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar',
                    'lib\\sqljdbc4-3.0.jar')
    destinationDir = file('bin')
    source = fileTree('src')
    sourceCompatibility = '1.7'
    targetCompatibility = '1.7'
}

task clean(type: Delete){
    delete 'bin'
}

task init(type: Copy){
    //TODO: Create "bin" directory if it doesn't exist
    from 'src'
    into 'bin'
    exclude '**/*.java', '**/*.bak'
    includeEmptyDirs = false
}
```

and when I execute the `compile` task, I get the following exception

```
[sts] -----------------------------------------------------
[sts] Starting Gradle build for the following tasks: 
[sts]      :compile
[sts] -----------------------------------------------------
:clean
:init
:compile

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem was found with the configuration of task ':compile'.
> No value has been specified for property 'dependencyCacheDir'.

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskValidationException: A problem was found with the configuration of task ':compile'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:41)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:42)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:247)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.executeTask(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:192)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.doExecute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:177)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:83)
    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:36)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:67)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.TaskCacheLockHandlingBuildExecuter$1.run(TaskCacheLockHandlingBuildExecuter.java:31)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess$1.create(DefaultCacheAccess.java:111)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:126)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:109)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.useCache(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:103)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.java:79)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.TaskCacheLockHandlingBuildExecuter.execute(TaskCacheLockHandlingBuildExecuter.java:29)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:67)
    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:155)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:110)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:78)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:31)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ConfiguringBuildAction.run(ConfiguringBuildAction.java:94)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.protocol.Build.run(Build.java:68)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.protocol.Build.run(Build.java:64)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:45)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:45)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartStopIfBuildAndStop.execute(StartStopIfBuildAndStop.java:28)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ReturnResult.execute(ReturnResult.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$4.call(ForwardClientInput.java:116)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$4.call(ForwardClientInput.java:114)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:114)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:61)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.doBuild(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:49)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.HandleStop.execute(HandleStop.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.CatchAndForwardDaemonFailure.execute(CatchAndForwardDaemonFailure.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.HandleClientDisconnectBeforeSendingCommand.execute(HandleClientDisconnectBeforeSendingCommand.java:21)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StopConnectionAfterExecution.execute(StopConnectionAfterExecution.java:27)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DefaultDaemonCommandExecuter.executeCommand(DefaultDaemonCommandExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.Daemon$1$1.run(Daemon.java:123)
    at org.gradle.messaging.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:66)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.InvalidUserDataException: No value has been specified for property 'dependencyCacheDir'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:46)
    ... 68 more


BUILD FAILED
```

Why does compiling a java project require the `dependencyCacheDir` to be defined? And when I define the dependency cache dir, it complains that it cannot find the System Java Compiler.

What? Why!? What gives, gradle? This whole experience has been very frustrating and unnecessarily complicated..about to give up on it altogether.

Comment: May I ask why you don't want to use the java plugin ?

Comment: @DavidLevesque, I find it difficult to work with/customize. A lot of the implementation details are either esoteric, or hard to find. The documentation is crap and the examples assume a certain amount of gradle know-how that any beginner is going to clearly lack.

Comment: @mre: The compile task is part of the Java plugin. If you don't want to use the Java plugin, don't use the compile task. It makes all sorts of assumptions about things set up by the plugin (like the dependency cache dir, and indeed the very fact that you are using dependency management) which are entirely reasonable, but won't hold in your case. If you want to compile Java without using the plugin, then write a simple task which runs javac in a subprocess or something. Or use `AntBuilder` to use Ant's compile task!

Comment: Asking "What gives, gradle?" is a bit like asking "What gives, electric drill?" as you try to put a hole in a wall without having plugged it into the mains because you find electricity difficult to work with/customize. This is not a problem with Gradle; this is a problem with your use of Gradle.

Comment: @TomAnderson, I agree, it is a problem with my use of Gradle, but isn't the documentation supposed to circumvent this sort of thing? Instead, I find myself going deeper and deeper into the rabbit hole, thanks Gradle! ;]

Comment: If you follow the documentation's advice on how to use the compile task (ie apply the java plugin, use configurations to define source directories and dependencies, etc), then i suspect it will work (it does for me). You're not trying to *use* Gradle, you're trying to *misuse* Gradle. Frameworks (of which Gradle is certainly an example) have a grain, like wood; if you go with the grain, they can make life easier, but if you go against it, they will always make it harder. Your choice should be between going with the grain, and not using the framework at all.

Comment: @TomAnderson, Also, if the compile task is part of the java plugin, why can I use it without having to explicitly apply the java plugin?

Comment: Honestly, it's entirely reasonable not to like the way Gradle does things. I know plenty of people who don't. But in that case, i think the prudent move would be to use something else! Or, perhaps, to use it as a "better Ant", and just write tasks yourself in Groovy.

Comment: Sorry to hear you're being forced to use it. That is never fun. At this point, you have two choices: use it as it was intended to be used (ie learn how to use the Java plugin), or fall back to simply writing tasks in Groovy. There's certainly a lot less baffling magic going on if you do the latter.

Comment: Three weeks later, and i find myself in exactly this position. I want to use custom `Compile` tasks to run some annotation processors without actually compiling anything, and Gradle is moaning about not having `dependencyCacheDir` on them. Oh well, live by the sword, die by the sword.

Answer (score 4):

In case you should ever decide to use the Java plugin:

```
apply plugin : 'java'

sourceCompatibility = '1.7'
targetCompatibility = '1.7'

sourceSets {
   main {
      java {
         srcDirs = ['src']
      }
   }
}

buildDir = 'bin'

repositories {
    flatDir dirs: 'lib'
}

dependencies {
    compile ':foo-agent-dist:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT',
            ':foo-common:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT',
            ':foo-communication-api:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT',
            ':spring-beans:3.1.2.RELEASE',
            ':spring-context:3.1.2.RELEASE',
            ':spring-web:3.1.2.RELEASE',
            ':sqljdbc4:3.0'
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You would probably have better luck using the [JavaCompile](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.html) task type.

Answer (score 2):

Why aren't you using the Java plugin? Configuring everything by hand will take more effort.

If you need help on the "system java compiler" error, please post the error message and stack trace.

Comment: Please see my response to @David Levesque above. And I've resolved the "System Java Compiler" issue already...I pointed Gradle (in Eclipse) to the jdk instead of the jre. So I'm now able to compile my Java project, but I have this stupid "dependency-cache-dir" folder in my "bin" directory.

Comment: Please be more specific. And by the way, your tone won't help to attract people spending their time on helping you out.

Comment: Be more specific!? Really? I've included code and stacktraces. What else could you possibly be looking for? I'd like to see what your tone would be like after spending nearly a week trying to convert a simple Ant script to Gradle. Don't get all butthurt because you're part of the Gradle development team.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me, just apply necessary changes to your code having this as example

```
apply plugin: 'java'

configurations {
     querydslapt
}

sourceSets {
     target
}

sourceSets.target.java.srcDirs = ['src/main/target']


dependencies {
    compile ...libraries....

        querydslapt 'com.mysema.querydsl:querydsl-apt:2.7.1'

    testCompile project(':fastappoint-test')
}

task generateQueryDSL(type: Compile, group: 'build', description: 'Generates the QueryDSL query types') {
         source = sourceSets.main.java
         classpath = configurations.compile + configurations.querydslapt
         options.compilerArgs = [
                "-proc:only",
                "-processor", "com.mysema.query.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor"
         ]
         destinationDir = sourceSets.target.java.srcDirs.iterator().next()
         dependencyCacheDir = new File(destinationDir, "dependencyCacheDir")
}
compileJava.dependsOn generateQueryDSL
```